# how to send sms in java, my concern is regaridng the sms gateway

Tags: sms

I want to send SMS to my mobile through my java application, but could someone please explain how to do this, i already had the java code, but my concern is regarding the SMS gateway.

Answer (score 0):

There's also low cost APIs - certainly not free :

[Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/)

[Nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As Adeel mentioned above, you can implement an SMS API such as Nexmo into your program.

After signing up, you are provided with a few account details such as your api_key & api_secret.

What you will need to do is just make an HTTP call

**Github Java SDK**: https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-java-sdk

You need to copy the nexmo-sdk.jar & some library dependencies under /lib directory (if not already included) to your application and ensure that it is in your classpath

To submit a message, first you should instantiate a NexmoSmsClient, passing the credentials for your Nexmo account on the constructor. Then, you should instantiate the appropriate Message subclass depending on which type of message you are going to submit

Depending on the country (United States for example), the cost starts at just fraction of a penny!

*Full Disclosure: I work for Nexmo*

**Detailed instructions for the installation of Nexmo's Java SDK can be found:** https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/pre-built-libraries